# Find all coefficients of a polynom function 4th grade

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> $$
> \begin{array}{l}{\text {  } \left() \text {   } f(t)=(\cos (2 t)-i \sin (2 t))^{2}, t \in \mathbb{R}, \text { stated function }\right.} \\ {\text { is a trig polynom  grade } 4 \text { and can be rewritten as }} \\ {\qquad f(t)=\sum_{k=-4}^{4} c_{k} e^{k i t}} \\ {\text { as well as }}\end{array}
> $$$$
> \begin{array}{l}{\qquad f(t)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{j=1}^{4}\left(a_{j} \cos (j t)+b_{j} \sin (j t)\right), \quad t \in \mathbb{R}} \\ {\text { with  coefficents } c_{k} \text { or } a_{j}, b_{j} \text {  }} \\ {\text { specify all coefficients } c_{k} \text { for }-4 \leq k \leq 4 \text { as well } a_{0} \text { and } a_{j}, b_{j} \text { für } 1 \leq j \leq 4 \text { }}\end{array}
> $$

---

literally no clue i know nothing about that one. Appreciating any help

Comment: Hint: $\cos(2t)-i\sin(2t) = e^{-2it}$

Comment: don't know what to do with that

Comment: Hint2: $(e^{-2it})^2 = e^{-4it}$.

Comment: $$
\sum_{k=4}^{4} (-1)^{k}/(k) e^{-4 i t}
$$ ?

Comment: By definition, $\sum\limits_{k=-4}^4 c_k e^{ikt}$ is a short hand for $$c_4 e^{i4t} + c_3e^{i3t} + c_2 e^{i2t} + c_1 e^{it} + c_0 + c_{-1}e^{-it} + c_{-2}e^{-2it} + c_{-3}e^{-3it} + c_{-4} e^{-4it}$$
If this sum equals to $e^{-4it}$, what are $c_{4},c_{3},\ldots,c_{-4}$?

Comment: all zero except c-4 which has to be one so i tried to find values for all haha